# SVG: Remove element from svg using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg

I add a foreignObject insider g element in svg the html is as follow:

```
<g id="group" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,3700,20)">
<rect x="80" y="80" stroke="black" id="occ" style="stroke-width: 10px; stroke: rgb(0, 128, 255);" width="140" height="140" fill="white" class="marked"></rect>
<foreignObject id="fo_1" x="29" y="29" width="18" height="18" transform="scale(4,4)"><div style="color: brown; stroke: rgb(0, 128, 255); stroke-width: 10px;" class="marked"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></div></foreignObject>
</g>
```

I added the foreignObject when the rect is clicked with command:

```
element.parentElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<foreignObject ...>);
```

But then I fail to remove the foreignObject again if the rect is clicked again. At the moment, I have successfully find the foreignObject element by using ID, but still cannot remove it.

I tried the code like below:

```
$('svg').find('foreignObject#fo_1').remove();
```

or this code:

```
var foreignObj = document.getElementById('fo_1');
var parent    = foreignObj.parentNode;
parent.removeChild(foreignObj);
```

Anyone can help please? Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you have inserted more than one `<foreignObject>` with the same ID, so when you try to remove, you remove the first one but the others remain in the DOM?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can see what's happening for ourselves.